# El formato y la extensión excel "xls" no coinciden

Tags: php, phpexcel

[image: Si le doy que sí al recuadro me abre el excel pero mal]
Tengo esta fraccion de codigo para hacer un ejemplo con PHPExcel, pero a la hora de generar el pdf y abrirlo me dice excel: "El formato y la extension de archivo de excel nombre.xls no coinciden", ¿Alguna idea de porque sale eso, ya busqué solucionar el problema pero, aun no funciona?

```
    require_once('shared/PHPExcel.php');

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()
        ->setCreator("Códigos de Programación")
        ->setLastModifiedBy("Códigos de Programación")
        ->setTitle("Excel en PHP")
        ->setSubject("Documento de prueba")
        ->setDescription("Documento generado con PHPExcel")
        ->setKeywords("excel phpexcel php")
        ->setCategory("Ejemplos");

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Hoja 1');

            // Agregar en celda A1 valor string
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','PHPExcel');
            // Agregar en celda A2 valor numerico
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A2',12345.6789);
            // Agregar en celda A3 valor boleano
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A3', TRUE);
            // Agregar a Celda A4 una formula
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A4','=CONCATENATE(A1, " ", A2)');

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Excel.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file2.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");


    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: ¿Lo descargas como Excel.xls o file2.csv?

Comment: Lo descargo como Excel.xls

Comment: Tu código declara el content-type y el content-disposition dos veces, la segunda vez como csv